# How to import all Vue components from a folder?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to load all my vue's components automatically from a folder,
which is working fine if I **don't use** vue "[Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)".

Once I try to use Async Components with **import** .. I get this error:

```
10:11-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

My code that load all components, which generate this error:

```
const ComponentContext = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);

ComponentContext.keys().forEach((componentFilePath) => {

    const componentName = componentFilePath.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
    Vue.component(componentName, () => import(componentFilePath));

});
```

How to fix this ? or is there is any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I needed to add 'lazy' in:

```
const ComponentContext = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i, 'lazy');
```

and then:

```
Vue.component(componentName, () => ComponentContext(componentFilePath));
```

Comment: Ok, this is NOWHERE to find, spend hours searching, should be mentioned anywhere in docs. Testing now, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had to merge the question with an answer here to get this final solution:

```
const ComponentContext = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i, 'lazy');

ComponentContext.keys().forEach((componentFilePath) => {

    const componentName = componentFilePath.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
    Vue.component(componentName, () => ComponentContext(componentFilePath));

});
```

The `'lazy'` third param was added to `require.context()`, and `() => import()` was changed to `() => ComponentContext()`.

I can see the bundles in the Network tab of the dev tools pane, and I don't see the bundles when I navigate to a page that doesn't render any of the auto-loaded components.

Therefore, I am reasonably-certain the above code is autoloading and dynamic importing. I will also confirm that in my project, I am using:

```
require.context('~/components/common', true, /\.vue$/i, 'lazy')
```

Note where mine is different at `~/components/common` compared to `./`. Your project needs will likely be different. In mine, the `~` is a Webpack alias for `/resources/js`, so my full path would be `./resources/js/components/common`. The rest of the code above is an algorithm, and can remain untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Vue.component(componentName, () => import(componentFilePath));
```

Try

```
Vue.component(componentName, ComponentContext(componentFilePath));
```

Or

```
Vue.component(componentName, ComponentContext(componentFilePath).default);
```

not sure about the default part.

Comment: That doesn't do an async import anymore, which is specifically what OP wants to do.